# including html menu bar from another html file

Tags: html, file, include

I have 2 html files x and y.html. And I try 2 different ways to solve this problem:How I include html files wihout iframe and javascript?

it is menu file y. html

```
<!--sidebar start-->
    <aside>
    <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">
    <!-- sidebar menu start-->
    <div class="leftside-navigation">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="index.html">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub-menu">
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
                    <span>Lists</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="form_component.html">Shopping List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="advanced_form.html">To-Do List</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="profile.html">
                <i class="fa fa-glass"></i>
                <span>Profil</span>
            </a>

        </li>


      <!-- sidebar menu end-->
  </div>
</aside>
<!--sidebar end-->
```

an it is main index page x.html

```
    <!--sidebar start-->
<aside>
    <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">
        <!-- sidebar menu start-->

               <!-- MENU SHOULD BE HERE-->  

        <!-- sidebar menu end-->
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with html.

But you can use PHP

```
<?php include("menu.html"); ?>
```

So in your case:

```
    <!--sidebar start-->
<aside>
    <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">
        <!-- sidebar menu start-->

               <?php include("menu.html"); ?>   

        <!-- sidebar menu end-->
    </div>
</aside>
```

Make sure your server supports PHP.

Comment: whta are the alternatives for HTML + Jquery pages?